# Does changing resistance of resistor connected parallel to voltmeter change the output voltage of it?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits

Here is the circuit.

[image]

My own logic says that the voltage output should stay the same even if the resistance of the resistor is increased because in parallel the voltage is equal.

Comment: your logic is correct

Comment: Would anything change if we took into consideration internal resistance of the battery and the electromotive force?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: You need to consider the internal resistance of the battery, and as I said last time this came up, without *numbers* we can't say whether or not the battery's resistance with have an important effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A voltmeter has a very high internal resistance, typically around $1M\Omega$. So when it is used in circuits with much smaller resistances $R$ of tens of $k\Omega$ or less, it draws very little current. Then practically all of the current from the battery flows through the battery and the load resistor $R$.

The internal resistance $r$ of a battery is typically $0.1-2\Omega$. In your circuit the emf $V$ of the battery is divided proportionately between $r$ and $R$ so the voltmeter will read $\frac{R}{R+r}V$.

If $R\gg r$ then all of the emf of the battery appears across the load resistor, so the voltmeter will read $V$. Reducing load resistance $R$ reduces the reading of the voltmeter. When $R=r$ the voltmeter reads $\frac12V$. If $R \ll r$ then the reading on the voltmeter is very small, close to zero.

Comment: An _ideal_ voltmeter has infinite resistance.  A DIY-store DMM will have an input impedance of maybe one megOhm.  A lab-grade DMM will be at least an order of magnitude better than that.

Answer (score 0):

Voltmeter measures the resistance between the two points in which it is connected.

Only thing these two points have in the middle is the cell.So the voltmeter will only measure the potential difference due to cell.

Analogy:[image]